# How secure is HTML5 local Storage for a Mobile Device

Tags: security, html, mobile, local-storage

I'm looking to work around some performance issues on a mobile site by storing the data entered on multiple forms into the local Storage.

I will be clearing the data on load and clearing the data on the last page, so no sensitive data will be left on the device after they visit the website on their mobile device.

I do have a couple of concerns though:

- Can another program access the data I store in local storage?
- If the user doesn't complete the process can I place a expiration date on the data?

  Example: I want the data to expire in 30 minutes regardless if the user has finished the process, left the site, closed the browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at sessionStorage, which works similarly to localStorage but doesn't keep any data once a tab/window/browser is closed.

This would also be more secure than localStorage as no data would be kept once a session has ended. There is more details on security in the [W3 Storage spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#security-storage).

However if you're storing sensitive data I'd recommend cookies as data in sessionStorage and localStorage can be viewed and edited by the user and is potentially open to XSS attacks.

Comment: Thanks, I do like the sessionStorage, but why do you say that using a Cookie would be more secure for sensitive data? Could you explain a little more

Comment: Mostly because it can be more easily viewed (although you would need to know the value name to get any data), there's some good points in this MS article on DOM storage, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197062(v=vs.85).aspx#_privacy

Comment: I think the phrasing in the answer a little bit misleading. Do **not** use cookies to store sensitive data.